# Java : Create new ArrayLists based on some condition from existing ArrayList

Tags: java

I am new to java .

I have 2 ArrayLists of Strings

```
List<String> a= [2,14]
List<String> b= [2,3,4,5]
```

I want two new ArrayLists

1) List has the value which is in `b` but not in `a`

```
  List<String> c= [3,4,5]
```

2) List has the value `a` but not in `b`

```
  List<String> d=[14]
```

I tried:

```
    List<String> c = new ArrayList<String>(b);
    c.removeAll(a);
   System.out.println("c::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+c);  // 2,3,4,5
```

which is not removing the values of List a

Complete Code

```
   public static void updatePartyType(List<String> oldPartyKeys, List<String> newPartyKeys, String customerCode) {
   System.out.println("oldPartyKeys--->"+oldPartyKeys);// 2,14
   System.out.println("newPartyKeys--->"+newPartyKeys); // 2,3,4,5

   System.out.println("oldPartyKeys class --->"+oldPartyKeys.getClass());// class java.util.ArrayList

   List<String> newlySelectedPartyKeys = new ArrayList<String>(newPartyKeys);
   newlySelectedPartyKeys.removeAll(oldPartyKeys);
                    System.out.println("newlySelectedPartyKeys::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+newlySelectedPartyKeys);
```

Comment: Is the ordering important? These are set-based operations more than list-based ones.

Comment: it should be string list

Comment: Please edit the question to be a short but *complete* program - you've only given pseudo-code for the list initialization at the moment.

Comment: The code you've been trying **should work** which means the problem is elsewhere. You can go to my answer and see how it's done using your provided example using the same method you've tried.

Comment: That's still not complete code. Complete code is code which we can copy into a text editor, compile and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the [addAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) and [removeAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) in [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

now you need `b\a` which is `b.removeAll(a)`
and `a\b` which is `a.removeAll(b)`

A working example (this is for those who are new to Java, so it's verbose):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // first we want to create the lists

    // create list a
    List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    // add members to a
    a.add("2");
    a.add("14");
    // create list b
    List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
    // add members to b
    b.add("2");
    b.add("3");
    b.add("4");
    b.add("5");

    // create a list in which we store the "filtered" list - duplicated from
    // a
    List<String> aMinusB = new ArrayList<>(a);
    // "filter" using "removeAll" and giving the list b as the argument
    aMinusB.removeAll(b);
    System.out.println("A minus b:");
    // this is short for
    // "iterate over the entire list, naming the currently iterated node s"
    for (String s : aMinusB) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    // duplicate list b in the same manner as above
    List<String> bMinusA = new ArrayList<>(b);
    // "filter" using "removeAll" and giving the list a as the argument in
    // the same manner as above
    bMinusA.removeAll(a);
    System.out.println("B minus a:");
    // this is short for
    // "iterate over the entire list, naming the currently iterated node s"
    // in the same manner as above
    for (String s : bMinusA) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're really proposing set operations more than list operations - in which case you'd be better off using a `HashSet` than an `ArrayList`. Then you could use [`Collection<E>.removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
Set<String> a = ...;
Set<String> b = ...;

Set<String> c = new HashSet<String>(b);
c.removeAll(a);

Set<String> d = new HashSet<String>(a);
d.removeAll(b);
```

(This will work for `ArrayList` as well as `HashSet` - I've only changed to using sets because it's a more appropriate type when you want set-based operations.)

Or better, use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Sets.difference`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29) method:

```
Set<String> a = ...;
Set<String> b = ...;

Set<String> c = Sets.difference(b, a);
Set<String> d = Sets.difference(a, b);
```

This will create *views* on the differences - so changes to the original sets will be reflected in the views. You can effectively take a snapshot of a view by creating a new `HashSet`:

```
Set<String> snapshot = new HashSet<String>(c);
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by using the `removeAll` method:

```
List<String> c = new ArrayList<>(b);
c.removeAll(a);

List<String> d = new ArrayList<>(a);
d.removeAll(b);
```

Comment: @monda I've added an example

Comment: @monda: "not working" doesn't give us any significant information. What happened when you tried it? It should be fine.

Comment: @monda, I've added an example of a static "main" function in my code. You do know how to run a "main" function?

Simple drop my code in, import "List" and "ArrayList" (your IDE should mark this for you really...) and follow the comments in the code.

Comment: @Mureinik :Updated my question

Comment: @monda Maybe you only have Java 6.  This answer requires Java 7.  Try putting `String` inside each pair of `<>`.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your lists to `Set` instances. Then you can easily find the difference of sets by your own implementation or using a 3rd party library like *Google Guava* which has [`Sets.difference()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29), for example.

Comment: Beware that Sets.difference returns a view, not a new `Set`

Comment: @RC.: It returns a new `Set` instance - it's a view, but it's still a new set (`SetView` implements `Set`). It's not an *independent* set, but you could create one easily enough.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know but you can run into issues if you use the view directly (like adding something to it)

Comment: @RC.: My point is that claiming it's "not a new set" is misleading IMO. I've now mentioned that it's a view in my answer though.

Answer (score 1):

[`addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) elements, then [`removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) elements that appears in `a`.

The time complexity is O(n).